# Missing 'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip' file

Tags: python, windows, module, zip

I recently upgraded my Python 2.7.1 installation to 2.7.2 using the `.msi` installer and the process seemed to go OK. However afterwards I happened to be looking at what the default values were for `sys.path` and noticed the entry for 'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip'. Wondering exactly what was in it, I decided to try opening it with a Zip utility to check out its contents — however I soon discovered that the file wasn't there (although there is a `python27.dll`).

Anyhow I'm now wondering if something is wrong. Several existing Python programs I frequently use all seem to work without problems, so I'm not sure whether the installation is messed up or not (or how to fix it, if it is).

#### Update

I'm aware of and have read PEP273, so know about .zip file modules. That's not what I'm asking about. What I want to know is the fact that there is no `python27.zip` installed on my system even though it's referred to in my `sys.path` a problem? I've never encountered problems importing standard Python libraries, which is what I would expect not having one would affect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From PEP 273 -- Import Modules from Zip Archives](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/):

> Just as sys.path currently has default directory names, a default zip
>   archive name is added too.  Otherwise there is no way to import all
>   Python library files from an archive.
>
> ...
>
> The problem is what the name should be.  The name should be linked
>   with the Python version, so the Python executable can correctly find
>   its corresponding libraries even when there are multiple Python
>   versions on the same machine.
>
> We add one name to sys.path.  On Unix, the directory is sys.prefix +
>   "/lib", and the file name is "python%s%s.zip" % (sys.version[0],
>   sys.version[2]). So for Python 2.2 and prefix /usr/local, the path
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.2/ is already on sys.path, and
>   /usr/local/lib/python22.zip would be added. On Windows, the file is
>   the full path to python22.dll, with "dll" replaced by "zip".  The zip
>   archive name is always inserted as the second item in sys.path.  The
>   first is the directory of the main.py (thanks Tim).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of and have read PEP273. From what is says it kind of sounds like not having a python27.zip might be an error or problem -- but as far as I can tell everything seems fine. I checked another machine with 2.7.1 on it and it's also missing this file. Anyway, I don't think your response answers my question.